# How to find the highest number in a 2-dimensional array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, loops

Hi all and thanks in advance for your help.

So I would like to find the highest number in a 2-dimensional array.
Below is the code:

```js
const matrix = [
  [2, 56, 10],
  [20, 34, 10],
  [23, 144, 26]
];
let maximum = matrix[0][0];
for (var row = 0; row < matrix.length; row++) {
  for (var col = 0; col < matrix.length; col++) {
    if (matrix[row][col] > maximum) {
      maximum = matrix[row][col];
    };
  };
};
document.write(' -- ', maximum);
```

**Here is my problem** -  Could you please help me to understand why when I have more numbers in the array I cannot see the highest number - Find below an example ):

```js
const matrix = [
  [2, 56, 10, 14, 422, 3242],
  [20, 34, 55, 100, 33, 422],
  [23, 12, 14, 26, 203, 233]
];
let maximum = matrix[0][0];
for (var row = 0; row < matrix.length; row++) {
  for (var col = 0; col < matrix.length; col++) {
    if (matrix[row][col] > maximum) {
      maximum = matrix[row][col];
    };
  };
};
document.write(' -- ', maximum);
```

Comment: Share the output as well please.

Comment: your code is wrong. `for(var col=0; col<matrix[0].length; col++)` It should be like this.

Answer (score 5):

`row < matrix.length` tests the correct thing. `col < matrix.length` does not: you should replace it with `col < matrix[row].length`.

However, there is an easier way, using some of the newer JavaScript features:

```js
const matrix = [[2,56,10,14,422,3242],[20,34,55,100,33,422],[23,12,14,26,203,233]];
const maximum = Math.max(...matrix.flat())
console.log(maximum);
```

`matrix.flat()` will flatten the two-dimensional array into one dimension, `...` syntax will put each value from the one-dimensional array as its own argument to `Math.max`, which then finds the biggest one.

Comment: I'm not going to bother testing, but I wonder if that is more or less efficient than `Math .max (... matrix .map (ns => Math .max (... ns)))`.

Answer (score 3):

There is one small mistake. When you iterate the column make sure you iterate the number of columns.

`matrix.length` gives you the number of rows and `matrix[i].length` gives you the number of columns.

```js
const matrix = [[2,56,10,14,422,3242],[20,34,55,100,33,422],[23,12,14,26,203,233]];
let maximum = matrix[0][0];
for(var row = 0; row < matrix.length; row++){
  for(var col = 0; col < matrix[row].length; col++){
    if(matrix[row][col] > maximum){
      maximum = matrix[row][col];
    };
  };  
};
document.write(' -- ', maximum);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are taking `matrix.length` for no. of column as well, but it gives you no. of rows i.e. 3  but in your case but no. of column is 6 . that's why it only check for 3 numbers

```
const matrix = [[2,56,10,14,422,3242],[20,34,55,100,33,422],[23,12,14,26,203,233]];
let maximum = matrix[0][0];
for(var row = 0; row < matrix.length; row++){
  for(var col = 0; col < matrix[0].length; col++){          <--- Correction
    if(matrix[row][col] > maximum){
      maximum = matrix[row][col];
    };
  };  
};
document.write(' -- ', maximum);
```

Answer (score 0):

Also can use [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) combined with [Math.max()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max):

```js
const matrix = [[2,56,10,14,422,3242],[20,34,55,100,33,422],[23,12,14,26,203,233]]

const maximum = matrix.reduce((a, c) => Math.max(a, ...c), 0)
console.log(maximum)
```